# Expected type 'Iterable' (matched generic type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThanT]')

Tags: python, python-typing

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True, order=True)
class C:
    x: int

l = [C(1), C(2), C(1)]
print(sorted(l))
```

The above code works but gives a warning:
`Expected type 'Iterable' (matched generic type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThanT]'), got 'list[C]' instead`.

I think the `order=True` param passed to `@dataclass` should result in generation of `__lt__` etc and thus confirm to `SupportsLessThanT`?

An explicit implementation of `__lt__` silences the warning, but how do I silence it without?

Comment: Is this warning coming from PyCharm or some other IDE? Seems like it's not handling dataclasses properly. Maybe try disabling that inspection in the settings or adding `#noqa` to the line

Comment: @rdas, yes, apparently a known bug in PyCharm. Closing this, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently a known bug in PyCharm, tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45958/Type-error-sorting-Iterable-of-dataclassorderTrue-instances)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit of additional context here, as it seems it isn't mentioned in the bug tracker explicitly...

This is a bug that likely stems from the fact that the `dataclass` magic is adding methods and annotations **dynamically**. Something that is not in the nature of static type checkers to pick up. They solve situations like this with special plugins that are *tailored* to certain specifications.

A related issue comes up when people try to mimic `dataclass`-like behavior in their own code, i.e. constructing signatures and/or adding annotations at runtime. They always run into the same obstacle of static type checkers being completely oblivious to their intent.

> Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it.

#### Related:

- [How to typehint dynamic class instantiation like pydantic and dataclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987319)
- [How can i type hint the init params are the same as fields in a dataclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778158)

I have no affiliation with the JetBrains folks. Just wanted to point this out to be fair because I would consider this a more "forgivable" bug as they are forced to "hack around" [PEP 557](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/).